# how to disable sending telemetry and log data to open ai when using Azure OpenAI Service

Tags: azure, openai-api, openai-whisper, azure-openai

I am working with security data and need to make sure we disable sending telemetry and log data to open ai when using Azure OpenAI Service

does anyone know how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You can [submit a form](https://aka.ms/oai/modifiedaccess) to request suppression of log data that is sent to the content filters.

More on privacy, including a section on the content filters, can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/openai/data-privacy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the form for modified content filters and abuse monitoring:https://customervoice.microsoft.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR7en2Ais5pxKtso_Pz4b1_xURE01NDY1OUhBRzQ3MkQxMUhZSE1ZUlJKTiQlQCN0PWcu

For Data Privacy and security please see: [Data, privacy, and security for Azure OpenAI Service - Azure Cognitive Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/openai/data-privacy?context=%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2Fopenai%2Fcontext%2Fcontext)